# dotnet restore fails in docker on 1 wifi, ok others

Tags: docker, .net-core, nuget, wifi

I have a local build of my dotnet core app that runs in the microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk image.  The dotnet restore part of this works perfectly fine on most connections but there is 1 wifi connection where I work and I get errors like:

```
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.numerics.vectors/index.json'.
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
```

If I try using curl to get the json file by manually running the image, it works ok:

```
PS C:\Dev\src\Deployment> docker run -it 6baac bash
root@99660525f031:/# curl https://api.nuget.org/v3- 
flatcontainer/system.buffers/index.json --ssl
{
  "versions": [
    "4.0.0-rc2-24027",
    "4.0.0",
...
```

I tried to 'forget' the connection and re-establish it.  Ive tried re-installing Docker.  Ive tried standing on my head.  Nothing seems to work - unless I move to another location and use an different wifi connection (or my docking station which I left in another country).

Does this make any sense to anyone??

Comment: This is an old question, still if you have the problem, post the Dockerfile please. Are you using the microsoft/dotnet:latest docker image ? Also what is your OS ?

Comment: Im fairly confident this is not related (directly) to docker or nuget but to the underlying windows connection.  Connecting via ethernet it works fine.  I havent retried wifi since doing that.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but I was using microsoft/dotnet:<older-tag>. Using microsoft/dotnet:latest fixed. But may be your case is different.

Comment: @Romaan : Oh well, maybe your right.  Im using microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk now - I prefer to control which version I use rather than :latest.  Cheers